# How to give validators in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, validation, database

I'm working on a backend with MongoDB. I have already done server side validation using node js, now I need to add validation at database level.

As of now I have  added one validator in MongoDB like this:

```
db.createCollection(name:("string"))
```

Could you please tell me how to give required validators, unique validators,  exists validators in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

*MongoDB provides the capability to validate documents during updates and insertions. Validation rules are specified on a per-collection basis using the validator option, which takes a document that specifies the validation rules or expressions.*

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/document-validation/

Example in order to check:
1) firstname (required)
2) lastname (required)
3) firstname (should be String)

```
db.runCommand( {
   collMod: "Test9",
   validator: { $and: [ 
                        { firstname: { $exists: true } }, 
                        { lastname: { $exists: true } },
                        { firstname: {$type: "string"}}
                      ] 
              },
   validationLevel: "moderate"
} )
```

Comment: Yeah ..I already saw this link..but there is only few validators ..I need to write require field kind of validator in MongoDB..can you exlain it how to write it?

Comment: You can't with just mongoDB. Maybe you can be interest in Mongoose that can make this validation client side.

Comment: @vkavsbsChandrapur i just update the Answer with some example

Comment: can u tell me what is the "Test9" in this line "collMod: "Test9"?

Comment: .its not working..it takes blank field as an input..required validators is not applying

Comment: @vkavsbsChandrapur you should add "{ firstname: {$ne: ""}}". Test9 is the name of the Collection.